# htaccess 301 redirect from URL with commas does not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a small handful of URLs, that I would like to 301-redirect in my .htaccess-file.

The problem is, that the original URLs contains some weird parameter formatting, that seems to break the redirect.

Basically I need this redirect to work:

```
redirect 301 "/index.php?id=365,0,0,1,0,0" http://example.com/about/
```

example.com also has a index.php file, but in my mind it should redirect anyway.

Anybody with insights on this one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `?id=365,0,0 ...` with `\?id=(\d\d\d.*)$`

OR

```
RewriteRule http://example.com/index.php?id=(\d\d\d.*)$ http://www./example.com/about/ [R=301,L]
```